# How to start writing in a file from new line. Have tried using \n, but isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter, file-handling

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Student Managment System')

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 350)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Welcome to the Library", fg = "White", bg = "Black")
canvas1.create_window(200,80, window = label1)

def Login():

    lab_ID = tk.Label(root, text = "ID")
    canvas1.create_window(90, 200, window = lab_ID)

    Password = tk.Label(root, text="Password")
    canvas1.create_window(90, 250, window=Password)

    ID_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window = ID_entry)

    Pass_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window = Pass_entry)

    def Writing_file():
        f = open("Data", "w")
        id = ID_entry.get()
        password = Pass_entry.get()
        f.write("{id} {password} \r\n".format(id = id, password = password))
        f.close()

    Login_Bt = tk.Button(root, text="Login", command = Writing_file)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 300, window=Login_Bt)

    def Reading_file():
        f = open("Data", "r")
        line = f.read()


button1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Student", bg = "yellow", fg = "Red", command = Login)
canvas1.create_window(150,150, window = button1)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Admin", bg = "Yellow", fg = "Red", command = Login)
canvas1.create_window(250,150, window = button2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you basically trying to do? You are trying to log users who sign in?

Comment: Like, I wanted to create a file that records the ID's and passwords for new users, on each line. This way, I could retrieve them by reading each line, to either login or to check if it already exists, while creating a new account.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("Data", "w")
```

`w` truncates the file contents when you write to the file. Try

```
f = open("Data", "a")
```

This will append instead.

See [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)